# How to push all these objects in different nested array into one array?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

```
(2) [Array(2), Array(1)]
0: Array(2)
0: {_id: '61cd4544264332414823198d', action: 'checkin', time: '2021-12-30T05:36:04.143Z'}
1: {_id: '61cd60713082f35340af2a87', action: 'checkout', time: '2021-12-30T07:32:01.986Z'}
length: 2
[[Prototype]]: Array(0)
1: Array(1)
0: {_id: '61cd455a26433241482319a5', action: 'checkin', time: '2021-12-30T05:36:26.346Z'}
length: 1
[[Prototype]]: Array(0)
length: 2
[[Prototype]]: Array(0)
```

I want all objects into one array like :

```
[
0: {_id: '61cd4544264332414823198d', action: 'checkin', time: '2021-12-30T05:36:04.143Z'}
1: {_id: '61cd60713082f35340af2a87', action: 'checkout', time: '2021-12-30T07:32:01.986Z'}
2: {_id: '61cd455a26433241482319a5', action: 'checkin', time: '2021-12-30T05:36:26.346Z'}
]
```

Comment: Try [`.flat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```
const input = [[{_id: '61cd4544264332414823198d', action: 'checkin', time: '2021-12-30T05:36:04.143Z'},
{_id: '61cd60713082f35340af2a87', action: 'checkout', time: '2021-12-30T07:32:01.986Z'}], [{_id: '61cd455a26433241482319a5', action: 'checkin', time: '2021-12-30T05:36:26.346Z'}]];

console.log(input.flat());
// output: > Array [Object { _id: "61cd4544264332414823198d", action: "checkin", time: "2021-12-30T05:36:04.143Z" }, Object { _id: "61cd60713082f35340af2a87", action: "checkout", time: "2021-12-30T07:32:01.986Z" }, Object { _id: "61cd455a26433241482319a5", action: "checkin", time: "2021-12-30T05:36:26.346Z" }]
```